# is_numeric eliminating negative numbers in Ruby

Tags: ruby, numeric, negative-number

I'm a new user here and also beginner with Ruby. I need to eliminate the negative values (numbers) from `is_numeric?`. So the code is this way:

```
class String
  def is_number?
    true if Float(self) rescue false
  end
end
```

That gives me positive and negative numbers while I need to get only the positive numbers. Is there a way to eliminate negative numbers in this method? If not then any other way is also appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class String
  def is_number?
    Float(self) >= 0 rescue false
  end
end
```

Comment: out of curiosity why you wrote the line `Float(self)`? what is the necessity of this line?

Comment: @iAmRubuuu: `Float` function raises an error if string can't be converted to number.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
class String
  def is_number?
    f = Float(self) 
    f && f >= 0
  rescue
    false
  end
end

'1'.is_number? # => true
'-1'.is_number? # => false
'0.0'.is_number? # => true
'4.12'.is_number? # => true
'-10_000'.is_number? # => false
```